# Can't use Jest to test responsive design using Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tailwind-css, react-testing-library, jsdom

I'm using TailwindCSS to implement a React App, and Jest to test it. I expect changing the window size can cause some elements to appear and disappear. Then I realized `jsDom` doesn't load TailwindCSS, and I followed [React testing library can't read styles using Tailwind CSS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010317/react-testing-library-cant-read-styles-using-tailwind-css-classes) and successfully injected the compiled CSS into `document.head` of `jsDom`. However, after I changed the window size by using

```
window.innerWidth = 480;
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
expect(window.innerWidth).toBe(480); // This passes
expect(screen.getByTestId("nav-bar-bottom")).not.toBeVisible(); // fails
```

the element that should be gone still exists.

I hear someone mentioned [jsDom doesn't support responsive test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281467/react-testing-library-rtl-test-a-responsive-design). So how responsive tests should be conducted then?